# Set an exception breakpoint for all exceptions except task cancellation

Tags: c#, exception, breakpoints, xamarin-studio

I want to set a breakpoint in my C#/Xamarin Studio project that breaks on all exceptions, EXCEPT those that have to do with task cancellation.  Is that possible?

Comment: You should use separate catch for cancellation exception...

Comment: I want to break on throw, so catching does not help.

Comment: So, you can use specify an exceptions in `Debug` -> `Exceptions` (VS2013) or `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Exceptions Settings` (VS2015)

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate catch for `CancellationException`

```
try
{
    //do your stuff here
}
catch(CancellationException ex)
{
    //behave cancellation
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Here handle other exceptions
    //Also you can put break point here
}
```

Comment: I need to break on throw; point is to break before the call stack unwinds.  So this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your entry point exactly, you could write a code like this:

```
try
{
   ....
}
catch (CancellationException)
{
     throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

     //otherwise handle this exception
}
```

If not, you could catch at application domain level using the event 
ApplicationDomain.UnhandledException. More details here: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/System.AppDomain.UnhandledException/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The typical use case for this is that I want to break on throw to see what is going wrong.  But I do not want to break for CancellationExceptions as those are not really errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. You may add catching all exceptions listening to System.Exception. Add the condition and check the type of exception in order to skip task cancelled exceptions. Exception in the local scope is available as $exception, so the condition will look like !($exception is System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException)